# to have had a good innings

Tags: idiom-meaning

I have heard it for the first time and when I looked it up on dictionaries, definitions say it means " to have had a long and fulfilling life or career". I think it is more a British slang.If I don't remember wrongly,  in the business context I heard it was used more like in the sense of " I am doing well" when someone mentioned how successful his new start-up company was.

I'd like to ask if it can be used for short time occasions or it  is always used to refer to a lifetime success.

For example, you organized your friend's wedding ceremony which may last one week and if someone asks " how is it going" by referring to the ceremony and everybody thinks the ceremony was perfect , can you say " I have had a good innings " in the sense " we are doing well" to refer to the ceremony.

Can someone who is 30 and  has a very good career say " I have had a good innings" ?

And is it common in the USA?

Comment: There is no such thing as a slang, you realize.

Comment: @tchrist No slang? Y'all just ain't shittin' me?

Comment: I wonder why this wasn't asked on ELL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a cricket metaphor, so it's not common outside cricket-playing nations.

Cricket works that you bat until you're out, then you stop (unlike, say, a baseball innings). For that reason you would almost always use it about something that is over. A life is the most common period of time, but someone who had, say, a successful period in charge of a company and was then ousted might use it too.

Comment: Very interesting. As an American, if someone said he had had *a good inning* (singular), I would take it as a baseball metaphor— a humble way of acknowledging recent success or good luck, but also acknowledging it as impermanent, whereas *a good innings* (plural) isn't grammatical unless you are familiar with cricket.

Comment: I would say that you *always* use it for something that is finished.  In the metaphorical sense, it  is never used for something in progress. If someone dies aged 20 then no-one would say 'She had a good innings'. That would be an insult to the mourners. If a man dies at the age of 90, then he has lived a long time and therefore it is appropriate to say he had a good innings. In terms of a life, a good innings is a long and healthy life. In terms of a business, it is only used if the person's career (or the business itself) is coming to an end - after along and successful period of operation.

Comment: When you get up to bat, at cricket, you 'have a good innings' if you stay a long time, batting. The expression 'he had a good innings' is used when something like work, or a lifetime, has gone on a long time, but then ended. It is used mostly in those contexts.